# What Extension In Visual Studio 2017 Disambiguates "bool" vs "std::function" When Passing In A Lambda?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, gcc, clang

The following compiles in Visual Studio 2017 with the MSVC compiler, but fails to compile in GCC or Clang.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void functionTest(std::function<void()>) {
    std::cout << "F\n";
}

void functionTest(bool) {
    std::cout << "B\n";
}

int main() {
    functionTest([](){ std::cout << "wut"; });
}
```

To fix this we can make use of enable_if like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void functionTest(std::function<void()>) {
    std::cout << "F\n";
}

template<typename BOOL_TYPE, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<bool, BOOL_TYPE>::value>::type>
void functionTest(BOOL_TYPE) {
    std::cout << "B\n";
}

int main() {
    functionTest([](){ std::cout << "wut"; });
}
```

Or I can disambiguate by introducing a user type instead of a bool (this is what you will need to do in the case of a constructor having the ambiguity problem):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void functionTest(std::function<void()>) {
    std::cout << "F\n";
}

enum class DescriptiveTypeName {False, True};
void functionTest(DescriptiveTypeName) {
    std::cout << "B\n";
}

int main() {
    functionTest([](){ std::cout << "wut"; });
}
```

The issue I'm having here is that I have a non-trivial sized game project and am trying to compile in Xcode for iOS. As far as I can tell I cannot get the same behaviour Visual Studio exhibits across all compilers (this would be nice). So as a result I am trying to edit my project to make it more conformant to the standard.

In an effort to do this in Visual Studio since it is my primary work environment I would like to know which non-standard extension is being used and how to disable it if at all possible. I can attempt to do this in Xcode, but for this particular problem I've found quite a few ambiguity issues and it only gives me a handful at a time.

As an additional curiosity I'm wondering if this ambiguous case has any standard proposal to address it or if Visual Studio is just going completely rogue in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda->bool conversion is actually lambda->function pointer->bool.  As one of these doesn't qualify as a "user defined conversion", the double-conversion is considered.

In MSVC, lambda has *multiple* lambda->function pointer conversions, one per calling convention.  This disagrees with the standard, where function pointers do not have calling convention types attached to them.

In any case, this should make the lambda->function pointer->bool conversion ambiguous (and trigger an error), but instead MSVC somehow decides to treat this ambiguity as an invalid overload instead of an error, and picks the one without ambiguity.  This also appears to violate the standard.

Together, these two standard violations generate the behavior you want, mostly by accident.

I believe we can work around it in a standard compliant manner without having to write manual SFINAE at each spot.  Here is an attempt:

```
template<class T>
struct exactly {
  T t;
  template<class U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, std::decay_t<U>>{}, int> =0>
  exactly( U&& u ):t(std::forward<U>(u)) {}
  exactly():t() {}
  exactly(exactly&&)=default;
  exactly(exactly const&)=default;

  operator T() const& { return t; }
  operator T() && { return std::move(t); }
  T& get()& { return t; }
  T const& get() const& { return t; }
  T get()&& { return std::move(t); }
};
```

now use:

```
void functionTest(exactly<bool> b) {
  std::cout << "B\n";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94c28b467b09e463).

Basically we move the fancy SFINAE into a utility class, thereby avoiding polluting the function signature with SFINAE.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution even though the other answer is more succinct just for the third method of disambiguation which allows for use of exactly<bool> as a regular parameter in a constructor.

Answer (score 7):

This is caused by the interaction of two things:

1. MSVC's captureless lambda has *many* conversion functions to function pointer - one per calling convention. As a result, converting a captureless lambda to `bool` via a function pointer is ambiguous in MSVC.
2. Instead of treating such an ambiguous conversion as being an *ambiguous conversion sequence*, [as the standard requires](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.best.ics#10), MSVC treats it as being no conversion sequence at all, which in turn means that the `bool` overload is not viable. That leaves the `function` overload as the only viable one.

The simplest way to disable the conversion to `bool` is to give the lambda a capture, or a capture-default - even if it doesn't end up capturing anything, having a capture-default is sufficient to disable the conversion to function pointer.

Comment: Why this should be ambiguous?  wouldn't actual call of lambda  require adding a call operator (which is illegal in OP's case, because  it does return void): `functionTest([]()->bool{ std::cout << "wut"; return true; }());` -note the extra ()

Comment: @Swift You misunderstand the ambiguity.  lambda to function pointer to bool (aka test for null) is the conversion sequence; MSVC has a myriad of different function pointer intermediate types.  It has nothing to do with calling the lambda or function pointer.

Comment: @Yakk Ah, because I wasn't thinking that such conversion is legal. wouldn't that be contextual conversion that is applicable only in certain cases. MSVC at doesn't see lambdas as a type convertible to bool, no bool operator defined in their implementation. function got the operator, but lambda never will be casted to function in this context

Comment: This is a good answer, thank you! I've gone with Yakk simply for the useful Exactly template.